# How to analyze the computational overhead of a Processing Sketch

Tags: processing, computation

Please forgive me if the terms are inaccurate or this is the wrong forum.

Essentially I write sketches in Processing and I am struggling to find out why my code runs slow.

Sometimes a sketch runs fast and I have no idea why other than there are less lines of code. Sometimes a different sketch runs slow and I have no idea why.

I am curious if there is a way within the Processing IDE, or maybe a general tool, to determine or analyze which lines of code are causing the sketch to run slow?

Such as a way to isolate "Oh, these lines are causing it to run the slowest. Looks like it's a section of this loop. Maybe I should concentrate on improving this function rather than searching for a needle in a haystack."

Similar to how when my computer is running slow I can use task manager to take a look at which programs are running slow and then adjust. I don't just guess. Or develop an unfounded penchant for quitting one program over another.

I of course could upload my sketch but this is a example independent problem I am trying to get better at solving. I would like to find a way to analyze all sketches. Or even code in different languages, etc.

If there is no general tool for analyzing a Processing sketch how do people go about this? Surely there must be a better method than trial and error, brute force, intuition, or otherwise. Of course those methods could yield better running code but there must be some formal analysis.

Even if you didn't have anything specific to share for Processing any suggestions on search terms, subjects, or topics would be appreciated as I have no idea how to proceed other than the brute force/trial and error method.

Thank you,

Comment: You are looking for a profiler. Not sure there's one for processing, but other languages have many, I usually use the visual studio built-in one.

Answer (score 1):

Without an example code snippet I can only provide a couple of general approaches.

The simplest thing you could do is use time sections of code and add print statements (poor man's profiler). The idea is to take a time snapshot before running a function/block of code you suspect is slow, take another one after then print the difference. The chunks of code with the largest time difference is what you want to focus on. Here's a minimal example, assuming `doSomethingInteresting()` is a function that you suspect is slow

```
// get the current millis since the sketch started
int before = millis();
// call the function here
doSomethingInteresting();
// get the millis again, after the function and calculate the time difference 
int diff = millis() - before;
println("executed in ~" + diff + "ms");
```

If you use Processing's default Java mode you can use [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) to sample your PApplet. In your case you will want to sample CPU usage and the nice thing about VisualVM is that you will the results sorted by the slowest function calls (the first you should improve) and you can drill down to see what is your code versus what is part of the runtime or other native parts of code.

[image: VisualVM profiling example]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for sharing that is a fantastic start! I have never heard of such tactics and I will be digging in to see what I can find!